# symlink in ubuntu I'am newbie

Tags: html5

I want to add a symbolic link to another folder
I want to say ln -sf / var / www / html to
/home / var / exemple / public
This is good.
/ home / var / example / public belongs to a user who creates.
in any case this is fine to do in production

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question and explain me what exactly you're trying to ask and do in here.

Comment: Read `man 7 symlink`

Comment: "exemple" -> "example" Typo in text or type in the command? :-)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to tell us what your goal is (where should be the symlink? where is the target?) and describe what the desired effect is and what you are getting instead. Copy the exact issued command into your question. If you get any error messages, copy them, too. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for pasted terminal text. Make sure you don’t enter paths with spaces around slashes to your terminal as you did in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

To create a symbolic link of `/var/www/html` in `/home/var/example/public`, you can

```
ln -s /var/www/html /home/var/example/public
```

maybe you meant the destination folder as `~/public` which will be in the same user.

Comment: Now I have a problem creating the link (ln -s /var/www/html /home/var/example/public)
the html folder is created
and it will not let me use the public folder
how to fix it

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but from what i understand you mean that there was an `html` folder created inside the `public` folder and instead you wanted the `public` folder to have the contents of the `html` folder? 
if so the delete the `public` folder and re run command. it will not create the `html` folder inside `public` but instead `public` folder will be the symlink folder.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped. Thanks